# Copy only content of directory not the entire path - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins *Post-build Actions* i have an action named *"Copy files back to the job's workspace on the master node"* where i want to copy all the content of indicated directory. Consider path: Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/* where "*" indicates all the content in Folder3.

My problem is: this copies not only entire content of Folder3 but the entire directory path to the job's workspace (directories: Folder1, Folder2, Folder3). How can I get rid of copying Folder1/Folder2/Folder3 and copy only all the content of Folder3 as it is indicated by "*" ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is this plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin
You can check the option **"Flatten Directories"** and you will only copy the content.